# c++ main not producing correct output

Tags: c++, function, loops, for-loop, integer

**Im having issues with my program. Its functionality should be able to read in a file from the input stream. The first number will be how many lines of code that need to be changed from duodecimal to decimal, then outputted. I just ran the code against,

3 /// number of lines to follow

13894

30-something

-Ex42

which my code should of outputted

27184

36

-20498

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong. Thanks for the feedback.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

/// -------------------- Function Prototypes -------------------- ///

/// Interprets a signed duodecimal value in the string dozenal. Skips any
/// whitespace characters (as defined by `std::isspace`) until the first
/// non-whitespace character is found, then takes as many characters as
/// possible to form a valid integer value.
///
/// The duodecimal value consists of the following parts:
///     * (optional) plus or minus sign
///     * a sequence of duodecimal digits 0-9,Xx,Ee (case ignored)
///
/// If the minus sign was part of the input sequence, the numeric value
/// calculated from the sequence of digits is negated.
///
/// @note If the value of the result cannot be represented, i.e., the
/// converted value falls out of the range of an int, behavior is undefined.
///
/// @param dozenal A string containing a signed duodecimal value
/// to be interpreted.
///
/// @returns The integer value corresponding to the content of dozenal
/// on success. If no conversion can be performed, 0 is returned.

int to_int(const std::string& dozenal);

/// Read the target number of iterations
/// @note target is on its own line
/// @param [out] target is user entered number of tests

void read_target(int& target);

using namespace std;

/// --------------------------------------------------------
/// Main Program
/// --------------------------------------------------------
int main (){

// variable declarations
int target;
std::string output;
int iterations;
std::string duoValue;

cin >> iterations;

for (std::string::size_type idx = 0; idx < iterations; idx++ ){
    cin >> duoValue;
    output = to_int(duoValue);
    cout << output << endl;
}
} /// main

/// --------------------------------------------------------
/// Function Implementations
/// --------------------------------------------------------

int to_int(const std::string& dozenal){

bool stop_on_first_non_digit = true;
size_t i = 0;
int decValue = 0;

while (i < duo.length() && std::isspace(duo.at(i)))
    ++i;

for (; i < duo.length(); ++i) {
    char c = duo.at(i);
    int digit = 0;
    if (duo.at(i) == '-' || duo.at(i) == '+')
        break;
    if (std::isdigit(c))
        digit = c - '0';
    else if (c == 'x' || c == 'X')
        digit = 10;
    else if (c == 'e' || c == 'E')
        digit = 11;
    else {
        if (stop_on_first_non_digit)
            continue;
    }
    decValue *= 12;
    decValue += digit;

    return decValue;
   } /// for loop
} /// to_int


/// Read the target number of iterations
/// @note target is on its own line
/// @param [out] target is user entered number of tests

void read_target(int& target){

  cin >> target;

}
```

Comment: Why does `to_int` both take a parameter and read from cin?

Comment: Actually your right, it should not be there

Comment: Function to_int does not always return a value, and also returns a value in the loop so probably too soon

Comment: What do you mean by 25 executable codes or less?

Answer (score 1):

In the original code, there were several bugs.

First, It did not compile at all and had several warnings. This was easy to fix. Change variable names, types and delete not needed stuff.

Then, you did put the `return` statement in the loop, so the function returns immediately in the first loop run. The `break`statement terminates the loop as well, so negative numbers will not be handled.

If you found a non-digit then you `continue`. But here you need to `break`. Because, if there will be a digit later, you would again use that number.

The handling of the first sign was wrong. If the first sign was consumed, then, from now on, it shall be a non printable and break.

Reading a `std::string`with a formatted input function `>>` will skip all leading white spacesd for you automatically.

This would make the following code, which is still bad and shall not be used. It still handles some test cases wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

/// -------------------- Function Prototypes -------------------- ///

/// Interprets a signed duodecimal value in the string dozenal. Skips any
/// whitespace characters (as defined by `std::isspace`) until the first
/// non-whitespace character is found, then takes as many characters as
/// possible to form a valid integer value.
///
/// The duodecimal value consists of the following parts:
///     * (optional) plus or minus sign
///     * a sequence of duodecimal digits 0-9,Xx,Ee (case ignored)
///
/// If the minus sign was part of the input sequence, the numeric value
/// calculated from the sequence of digits is negated.
///
/// @note If the value of the result cannot be represented, i.e., the
/// converted value falls out of the range of an int, behavior is undefined.
///
/// @param dozenal A string containing a signed duodecimal value
/// to be interpreted.
///
/// @returns The integer value corresponding to the content of dozenal
/// on success. If no conversion can be performed, 0 is returned.

int to_int(const std::string& dozenal);

/// Read the target number of iterations
/// @note target is on its own line
/// @param [out] target is user entered number of tests

void read_target(int& target);

using namespace std;

/// --------------------------------------------------------
/// Main Program
/// --------------------------------------------------------
int main() {

    // variable declarations
    int target;
    std::string output;
    int iterations;
    std::string duoValue;

    cin >> iterations;

    for (std::string::size_type idx = 0; idx < iterations; idx++) {
        cin >> duoValue;
        output = to_int(duoValue);
        cout << output << endl;
    }
} /// main

/// --------------------------------------------------------
/// Function Implementations
/// --------------------------------------------------------

int to_int(const std::string& duo) {

    bool stop_on_second_sign = false;;
    size_t i = 0;
    int decValue = 0;
    bool negative = false;
    while (i < duo.length() && std::isspace(duo.at(i)))
        ++i;

    for (; i < duo.length(); ++i) {
        char c = duo.at(i);
        int digit = 0;
        if (duo.at(i) == '-' || duo.at(i) == '+') {
            if (stop_on_second_sign) break;
            if (duo.at(i) == '-') negative = true;
            stop_on_second_sign = true;
        }
        else if (std::isdigit(c))
            digit = c - '0';
        else if (c == 'x' || c == 'X')
            digit = 10;
        else if (c == 'e' || c == 'E')
            digit = 11;
        else {
            break;
        }
        decValue *= 12;
        decValue += digit;
    } /// for loop
    return negative?-decValue:decValue;
} /// to_int

/// Read the target number of iterations
/// @note target is on its own line
/// @param [out] target is user entered number of tests

void read_target(int& target) {
    cin >> target;
}
```

Please see below a fully refactored solution. Please note. This is one of many possible solutions. It additionally gives user instructions and shows status messages.

With the many comments in it, you should be able to understand taht easily.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    
    // Read the number of conversions to be done
    unsigned int numberOfConversionsToBeDone = 0;
    // Get data from user and check, if input was ok
    std::cout << "\n\nHow many conversions shall be done?\n";
    if ((std::cin >> numberOfConversionsToBeDone) and (numberOfConversionsToBeDone > 0)) {

        //Now, in a loop, get all duo-numbers from the user and convert them
        while (numberOfConversionsToBeDone--) {

            // Read the string. Skip white spaces by using formatted input function
            std::cout << "\nPlease enter a duodecimal number:\n";
            std::string duoNumber; std::cin >> duoNumber;

            // Handling of sign is allowed only if no other digit has been read
            bool signIsAllowed = true;

            // Handling of negative numbers. We assume that number is positive
            bool numberIsNegative = false;
            
            // Here we will store the result
            int result = 0;
           
            // Analyze the string
            for (char c : duoNumber) {

                // Temporary storage for converted digit.
                int convertedDigit = 0;

                // First check the standard cases
                if (std::isdigit(c)) convertedDigit = c - '0';
                else if ((c == 'x') or (c == 'X')) convertedDigit = 10;
                else if ((c == 'e') or (c == 'E')) convertedDigit = 11;

                // Handling of sign
                else if ((c == '+') or (c == '-')) {

                    // Sign is allowed as first number symbol. Then not any longer
                    if (signIsAllowed) {
                        // Sign is ok to read. Evaluate negative number
                        numberIsNegative = (c == '-');
                    }
                    else { // We did not expect a sign as input here. Show message
                        std::cerr << "\nSign '" << c << "' not expexted here. Ignoring rest of input . . .\n\n";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // We did not expect a different character. Show message and stop
                    std::cerr << "\nDid not expect '" << c << "' here. Ignoring rest of input . . .\n\n";
                    break;
                }
                result = result * 12 + convertedDigit;

                // We will no longer allow for any further sign or for a sign at all.
                signIsAllowed = false;
            }
            // Make number negative if necessary
            if (numberIsNegative) result = -result;

            // Show result
            std::cout << "\nDuodecimal Number '" << duoNumber << "'   converted to integer:  " << result << "\n\n";
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n***Error: invalid number of test cases specified\n\n";
 }
```

Please note: In advanced C++ we would it differently. I will edit my answer later and show a advanced solution.

Please give me first a feedback about the solution at hand.

---

### Edit

And now one example for a more advanced C++ solution using build in functionality. As already said: Also here are many many different possible solutions.

This solution contains user instructions and complete error checking for all kind of errors. Note, without error checking, we have only 6 statements in `main`. The full solution has 13 statements in `main`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

const std::regex re{ R"(^\s*([+\-]?[0-9xXeE]{1,8}).*$)" };

int main() {
    // User instructions
    std::cout << "\n--- Duodecimal to int converter ---\n\n\nHow many conversions shall be done?\n";
    if (unsigned int conversionsToBedone{}; (std::cin >> conversionsToBedone) and (conversionsToBedone > 0u)) {

        // Do the number of conversions in a loop
        while (conversionsToBedone--) {

            // Try to read a duo-number
            std::cout << "\n\nPlease enter a duodecimal number:  ";
            if (std::string duoNumber{}; std::cin >> duoNumber) {

                // Search,m if the string contains a duo number att all
                if (std::smatch sm; std::regex_search(duoNumber, sm, re) and not sm.empty()) {

                    // Yes, we could see the duo number. Convert it and output it
                    duoNumber = std::regex_replace(std::regex_replace(duoNumber, std::regex("[xX]"), "a"), std::regex("[eE]"), "b");
                    std::cout << "\nResult of conversion: " << std::stoi(sm[1], nullptr, 12) << '\n';
                    // Check, if there were invalud characters in the string and show message
                    if (sm[1].length() != duoNumber.length()) 
                        std::cerr << "\n\n---Info. Invalid or too many characters in duo number. Ignored . . .\n\n";
                }
                else std::cerr << "\n\n***Error: Duo Number could not be found in input\n\n";
            }
            else std::cerr << "\n\n***Error: Could not read duo number\n\n";
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\n***Error: Invailid number of conversions given\n\n";
}
```